# Invalid use of int and no static main entry

Tags: methods, integer, program-entry-point

It says there is no suitable entry point for the program as well as invalid expression of int when attempting to use the printMenu method. My instructions specify that I need to initialize the array and menu in the main and utilize the 5 methods in a switch statement but I am tripping over the Main method. I am unable to understand how to reference an (int[] args) with a string. I was able to do it just fine with a switch statement but since moving onto methods I have struggled understanding how to reference properly and would appreciate any tops or fixes on how to adjust.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] initArray = new int[10];
            Console.Write("Would you like to: \n1) Enter a number\n2)Print the array \n3)find the sum of the array\n4)Reset the array\n5)Quit\n");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            printMenu(int[input]);

        }
            public void printMenu(int[] args)
            {


                Console.Write("Would you like to: \n1) Enter a number\n2)Print the array \n3)find the sum of the array\n4)Reset the array\n5)Quit\n");
                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                do
                {
                    switch (input)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            enterNum(args);
                            break;
                    }
                } while (input < 5);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the printMenu method like this:

```
printMenu(new int[]{ input });
```

If you have a second input you would do:

```
printMenu(new int[]{ input, input2 });
```

Using an array of integers is only logical when you want to pass in multiple integers. When you are never going to pass in more than 1 ints I suggest changing the signature of printMenu to ask for just one integer: `printMenu(int arg)` and just pass in the one input.

```
printMenu(input);
```